# freeipa Cannot obtain CA certificate error via ansible

Tags: centos7, ansible, freeipa

I am trying to install my freeipa replica server via [ansible role](https://github.com/freeipa/ansible-freeipa) and I have this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaclient/install/client.py", line 1858, in get_ca_certs
    message=u"HTTP "
fatal: [freeipa-r3]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "admin_keytab": null,
            "basedn": "dc=example,dc=local",
            "ca_cert_file": null,
            "debug": null,
            "domain": "example.local",
            "force_join": true,
            "hostname": "freeipa-r3.example.local",
            "kdc": "freeipa-m1",
            "keytab": null,
            "kinit_attempts": 5,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "principal": "admin",
            "realm": "EXAMPLE.LOCAL",
            "servers": [
                "freeipa-m1"
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "Cannot obtain CA certificate\nHTTP certificate download requires --force"
}
```

I tried adding "ipaclient_force_join=yes" option in the inventory file as noted in documentation, not really sure what I need to do.